# Unit Test in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, architecture, mstest

I've used mvc5 and Entity Framework 6 in my project. I decided to use *MSTest* in my project, but I have several questions.

For example I have a class that i called *Employee*, this class has several dependency to other classes in project for instance *company,organization,user*.
If i want create test method for an action in *Employee controller* that return an Employee regard to current user, company and organization in test method I have to create object for employee, user, company and organization  then I'll can test this action.

If I want create all objects for test, I have to create a lot of object in each test method this task is very time consumer also I have more complicated object with more dependency to the other object in my project.

I had research in this case,  some people recommended to create a database with specific data in it for test purpose, but I know one of the principle in unit test that is that have not been used a database and all test should be able run in memory.

If I want mock up all class is time consumer and possibility of error is high.

What is the best  approach to test in this situation ? 
Is a unit testing a good choice?

In the web most example is about write unit test for example phone number format or ... somethings like that where can I find proper sample ?

Answer (score 3):

I think you are confusing unit testing your controller with your repository classes.

If you want to do unit testing to your controllers, first you must make its dependencies to services "loosely coupled" using Dependency Injection.

Now, to load all Employee associated objects is a  responsibility of the repository service, not the controller. So you must not test that in your controller tests.

You must mock the repository service with a fake repository that returns an object with just the properties your controller need to do work. 
Then, in your controllers test, you must check that it does with this data what it has to do.
Of course, you can have multiple test to the same action testing different behavior for different types of data received.

- See ["Iteration #4 – Make the application loosely coupled"](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/contact-manager/iteration-4-make-the-application-loosely-coupled-cs) for an
  explanation with examples on how to use dependency injection with
  controllers.
- See ["Iteration #5 – Create unit tests"](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/contact-manager/iteration-5-create-unit-tests-cs), for how to unit test
  your controllers. Also [here](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TestHelper) you will find some tools to mock
  session and request data to unit test your controllers.

Testing the repository is a completely different task. This is more difficult because to really test it you need a real database. 
It depends on your situation, but what I use is a "Test database" that is cleaned and filled with some basic data (or regenerated if the schema has changed) each time some tests are started.

By the way, repository services only responsibility is to load classes from a database, so they don't need dependencies to other services and their tests never will use mocking.

Comment: thank you guys,as you said exactly i want Testing the repository but if i use data base I would lose advantage of unit testing

Answer (score 0):

By your question details I can say that not only unit testing should be involved, but actually the entire testing process must be set. My answer will be too broad, so I'll try to boil it down to these couple of suggestions:

- in order to gain proper testing activities, you need *Test environments* (at least one)
- unit testing is *just one of the (test) levels* that must be performed. As you know [Unit testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing) is all about *the smallest testable part of an application* and *nothing more*. If you need to cover complex objects creation, usage etc., maybe you need to consider another [test level](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/software_testing/levels_of_testing.htm). For example Integration Testing will help you with combined parts of your application and to determine if they function correctly together.

About the part with

> mock up all class

In many cases is inevitable to use such approach and even can improve performance. By proper combination of yours

> class has several dependency to other classes

For example I use such *mocked Test object* and cached it, so it can be reused in other test executions. Here very useful is the [Flyweight-design-pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/flyweight-design-pattern).

An year ago I had to work on such project (ASP .Net, Entity framework etc.) and as an answer to

> What is the best approach to test in this situation ?

To establish a serious [Test process](http://sqa.fyicenter.com/FAQ/Testing-Techniques/How_to_establish_QA_Process_in_an_organization_.html), that will help you with the reliability of your software.